# How to use shell script file docker volume?

Tags: bash, docker

I try build online compiler c++. This my `dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:latest

COPY . .
RUN apk update \
&& apk add build-base \
&& apk add g++


RUN [ "chmod","+x", "./judge.sh" ]
ENTRYPOINT [ "./judge.sh" ]
```

I write `judge.sh` file this for show what happening:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo 1
```

After successfully building image I run this command: `docker run -v $(pwd)/judge.sh test-judge` or `docker run test-judge` this command,  I get this same error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b064ecb567a905938f02177dcc73f8532556d24abb87dc10cd491cb5406548c6/merged/judge.sh
```

How to fix this error? And how to use `judge.sh` file in docker volume?

Comment: as I see,there is a conflict between the volume you are trying to mount and an existing file in the container.

Comment: Is it just a shell script?  That exists principally on the host?  You don't need Docker at all to run it; just run `./judge.sh`.

Comment: I use Windows OS. For time limit I need usr/bin/time command. For that I try use alpine + g++

Comment: Can you try `docker run -v $(pwd)/judge.sh:/judge.sh test` ?

Comment: If you are getting the error without defining any volume on `docker run`, that implies your Dockerfile contains a line like `VOLUME /judge.sh`, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

volumes and mounts are used on directories that contain files, not a single file.

in the Dockerfile, set the workdir before copying

```
FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app/
RUN apk update \
&& apk add build-base \
&& apk add g++


RUN [ "chmod","+x", "./judge.sh" ]
ENTRYPOINT [ "./judge.sh" ]
```

to run the copied judge.sh:

`docker run test` or `docker run test ./judge.sh`

to bind a directory with custom scripts

`docker run -it -v $(pwd):/app test ./judge.sh` or `docker run -it -v $(pwd):/app test ./custom_script.sh`

Answer (score 0):

You have `COPY . .` instruction in your dockerfile, which will copy all the contents where dockerfile is located, inside your image, including file judge.sh.

Now, when you run a container, it already has this judge.sh file inside it and you are also trying to mount the same file from outside the container and hence you are getting the error of

> cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists

Any reason why you need to both copy AND mount ?

Comment: I need use judge.sh file as docker volume for not build image every time

Comment: @FeruzAtamyradow then stop copying it with the `COPY . .`. Either omit that instruction, list specific files, or use `.dockerignore`. And of course you shouldn't have the `chmod` there then, because the file won't exist (abd you may need to use entrypoint of `/bin/sh ./judge.sh` instead if you are mounting from windows where the file won't be marked as executable).

Answer (score 0):

> ```bash
> docker run -v $(pwd)/judge.sh test-judge
> ```

You have not defined the source of the volume. Without that, it's an anonymous volume which is always an empty directory. Linux does not allow you to mount a directory where there is currently a file, there needs to be an empty directory instead.

To mount a file, you need to define the source and destination, e.g.:

> ```bash
> docker run -v $(pwd)/judge.sh:/judge.sh test-judge
> ```

The `:` separates the source on the host from the destination in the container.